# Get values from Class that will be created dynamically

Tags: reflection, java-ee-6, factory-pattern, java

I am trying to get values from a class in another class which will be created dynamically and also methods too. Check these examples i've gone through .

> InterfaceA.java

```
public interface InterfaceA{
    public ArrayList<?> getValues();
}
```

> ClassA.java / ClassB.java(consider another same class have value="World")

```
public Class A implements InterfaceA{
    String value = "Hello";

    public ArrayList<?> getValues(){
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add(this.value);
        return values ;
    }
}
```

> ClassC.java

```
public Class C{
    public void getValues(){
        Object modelObject;
        Method getValues;
        modelObject = resolveClass("A"); // arg = classPath
        getValues= modelObject.getClass().getMethod("getValues");
        getValues.invoke(modelObject);
        ArrayList<?> classValues;

        // How to access Class A values from here
        // I want to do These Lines
        // classValue = get value from A/B.getValues() dynamically
    }

    private Object resolveClass(String className) throws
    ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, 
    InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
    InvocationTargetException {
        Class<?> loadClass = Class.forName(className);
        Constructor<?> constructor = loadClass.getConstructor(String.class);
        Object object = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] {});

        return object;
    }
}
```

**How to access that method returned values as ArrayList<> mentioned in comments?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pseudo code...

```
Method m = .. getMethod("getValues");
Object o = m.invoke(modelObject);
ArrayList<?> classValues = (ArrayList<?>) o
```

you can find more info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

Comment: Is it possible to access ClassA variables with this "o" object.